# Haskell executable linking with static library written in C++ got `undefined reference`

Tags: haskell, ffi, cross-language

I've create a static library:

```
// foo.h
extern "C" {
int foo (const char* arg0, int arg1);
}

// foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"
// implementation of foo
```

This block of code was compiled to `foo.o` and packaged into `libfoo.a` which was installed to MinGW's `lib` dir (I'm on Windows, using GCC toolchain).

What I want to do is to wrap this function in Haksell code, so a typical FFI binding as follows:

```
-- Foo.hs
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Foo where

foreign import ccall "foo"
    c_foo :: CString -> CInt -> IO (CInt)
```

`extra-libraries` was added to the `.cabal` file as well:

```
...
extra-libraries: foo, stdc++
```

But GHC compains about undefined reference on `foo`:

```
.dist-scion\build\path\to\Foo.o:fake:(.text+0x514): undefined reference to `foo'
```

After `nm` the library to find out the function `foo` actually existing in the library (with some decorations on the name), I'm stucked here...

---

[EDIT]
I also tried build the haskell package using cabal:

```
cabal configure
cabal build
```

The result shows:

```
Loading object (dynamic) foo ... ghc.exe: foo: ....
<command line>: user specified .o/.so/.DLL could not be loaded (addDLL: could not load DLL)
```

So is this supposed to have something to do with static/dynamic linking? 'cause I noticed GHC want to load `.o/.so/.DLL` but NOT `.a`. I'm really confused.

---

finally got something on the wiki: [Cxx Foreign Function Interface](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cxx_foreign_function_interface)

---

***[EDIT]***
One solution is to use `-optl-lfoo -optl-lstdc++` in `.cabal` file, not `extra-libraries`. And the naming problem can be easily solved by wrapping the declaration in `extern "C"`:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern int foo (const char*, int);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

This works within EclipseFP, 'cause it uses Scion. But it still fails on `cabal build`.

Comment: Since you're on Windows, I think you need to change the foreign import statement to `foreign import stdcall "foo"`.

Comment: @JohnL : I use `nm` to inspect symbols in the .o file after adding `__stdcall` to the function, and get something like this: `00000000 T __Z18fooPKci@24`. GHC still says undefined reference to `foo@24`...

Comment: @clause: that symbol is C++ name-mangled. Are you certain that `foo` is declared inside an `extern "C"` block?

Comment: @DerrickTurk: no. But at first it IS in an `extern "C"`. I did some experiments, try to use `foreign import stdcall`, and failed.

Comment: @claude: I tried your original code and it works for me.  I built the library with `g++ -c foo.cpp; ar rcs libfoo.a foo.o; ghc ghc -lfoo Foo.hs`.  This is with g++-4.5.0 and ghc-7.0.3.  Is some of your code using Template Haskell, either directly or via fclabels or similar?

Comment: @JohnL: Yes, part of my code uses `peggy`, which involves `QuasiQuotations`. I suppose it is somehow TH related.

Comment: @JohnL: I tried my original code. It works fine with cabal build at the first build. After I delete the dist folder and try cabal build again, it fails with `user specified .o/.so/.DLL could not be loaded`

Comment: @claude: it may be TH related.  Since TH seems to want a .dll, can you build a .dll instead of a static archive?

Comment: @JohnL: If that's the case, it seems I don't have any other choice... thanks!

Comment: @claude: I'm pretty sure I don't understand completely what's going on, so there may be something else involved.  Can you share the full package, or an example which includes the peggy stuff?

Comment: @JohnL: I can send an example package to you via email.

Comment: @claude: sure, it's in my profile.  It'll probably take me a few days to respond though.

Comment: @JohnL: it seems we can't see each other's email address.

Comment: @claude: ok, try here then http://www.blogger.com/profile/14086288462709102194

Comment: @claude: You've probably solved this, but I just ran into and solved a problem that sounds similar (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562881/attempting-a-c-binding-to-haskell-getting-undefined-reference-errors).